# How can I change already created items to be under my newly created workflow?

Tags: workflow, powershell

Could Some one help me updating the workflow and workflow state field for all the sub items under the item say sitecore/content/ParentItem .

I have created a new workflow and set it up in standard values,But For the existing items i want to change the workflow to new Workflow and state to new Workflow State .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the workflow for the current item’s descendants, you can use the below script

```
$contentsToUpdate = Get-Item master: -Query "sitecore/content/ParentItem//*" -Language "en-GB"

foreach($content in $contentsToUpdate) {        

    $content.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $content.Fields["__Default workflow"].Value = "Item ID of Default Workflow"
    $content.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value = "Item ID of Workflow state"
    $content.Fields["__Workflow"].Value = "Item ID of Workflow"
    $content.Editing.EndEdit()

}
```

Note the `-Language` is equals to `en-GB`. Change it according to the language you want to update.

Answer (score 1):

Following blog post contains script 
https://mtgeekblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/first-blog-post/

```
function SetWorkflow($item)
{
  ## Update only items assigned __Default workflow
  if ($item.”__Default workflow” -eq “{A5BC37E7-ED96-4C1E-8590-A26E64DB55EA}”) {
    $item.__Workflow = “{A5BC37E7-ED96-4C1E-8590-A26E64DB55EA}”;
    $item.”__Workflow state” = “{190B1C84-F1BE-47ED-AA41-F42193D9C8FC}”;
  }
}

## Update correct workflow information.
## Uncomment below two lines if you are ready to go for updating
#get-item . -Language * | foreach-object { SetWorkFlow($_) }
#get-childitem . -recurse -Language * | foreach-object { SetWorkFlow($_) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do reset for existing items

```
Set-Location -Path "master:/sitecore/content/ParentItem"

function Reset-Workflows {

    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem . -Recurse)
    {
        foreach ($versionItem in $item.Versions.GetVersions($true))
        {
            Write-Host "trying update an item " $versionItem.ID
            if ($versionItem.Fields["__Default workflow"].Value -eq "[old_workflow_id]")
            {
                $versionItem | Reset-ItemField -Name "__Workflow state" -IncludeStandardFields
                $versionItem | Reset-ItemField -Name "__Default workflow" -IncludeStandardFields
                $versionItem | Reset-ItemField -Name "__Workflow" -IncludeStandardFields

                Write-Host "Item updated: " $versionItem.ID " - " $versionItem.Language;
            }
        }   
    }

}

Reset-Workflows
```